# Liferay can not build first plugin project

Tags: eclipse, liferay

I'm beginning with Liferay. Installed the Liferay Eclipse plugin, which worked fine. Configured the Liferay Server Runtime, which also worked fine. When it comes to create my first Liferay plugin project, it fails finishing this wizard tool.[image: Liferay Create Plugin Project Wizard]

It never finishes. I tried already downloading the ivy cache files and putting it manually inside .ivy folder. Didn't work either. A strange thing that I noticed is that after doing this, when I tried to launch another try in Eclipse, it created another .ivy inside the original .ivy folder. So it pretty much ignored the original .ivy and started doing the same process within the original .ivy.

This is what appears on the Eclipse Console :

```
[Console output redirected to            file:/Users/tutuk/.metadata/.plugins/com.liferay.ide.sdk.core/sdk.log]
Buildfile: /Users/UserName/Desktop/liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2/portlets/build.xml
[mkdir] Created dir: /Users/UserName/Desktop/liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2/.ivy
[get] Getting: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/ivy/ivy/2.3.0/ivy-2.3.0.jar
[get] To: /Users/UserName/Desktop/liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2/.ivy/ivy-2.3.0.jar
[ivy:resolve] :: Apache Ivy 2.3.0 - 20130110142753 :: http://ant.apache.org/ivy/ ::
[ivy:resolve] :: loading settings :: file = /Users/UserName/Desktop/liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2/ivy-        settings.xml
```

And when I force it to stop, on the Error Log appears this:

```
 Source '/Users/UserName/.metadata/.plugins/com.liferay.ide.sdk.core/create/1417376098997' does not exist
```

I am using liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2, liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga2 and jdk8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the permissions of all folders involved in the task to 777. It worked :)

Comment: You are operating system is windows or Linux?

Comment: I'm running this on a OS X operating system