# An error creating a plugin with Liferay and Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, liferay

I'm using Liferay 6.2 GA4 with the GA4 SDK and Eclipse Indigo Service Release 2.

I try to create a plugin, but it gives me an error. The Eclipse console doesn't show one, and it says it created the plugin successfully... but then it gives me an alert that there was an error, and to check Eclipse log file.

I go there and see this:

```
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Source 'C:\Users\kornjjuan\myproject\.metadata\.plugins\com.liferay.ide.sdk.core\create\1431291735742' does not exist
```

I go to the path and it only goes to com.liferay.ide.sdk.core, there I find only a sdk.log file, with the eclipse console log that the plugin was created successfully.

I've seen the log of the dependency downloads, but see no error in it, it gets a

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

I'm using ant plugins. What is happening?

Comment: Which OS you are working on?

Comment: With "C:\..." it's obviously windows. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30151962 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30151962 to see if these solutions apply on windows as well.

Comment: this permissions post sounds like it could be it... will try this

Comment: this wasnt it! sounded like a good answer... any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

found whats happening in the liferay forums, its a bug and they are working on it... ill leave it here for future references:

the posts are:

https://www.liferay.com/es/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/53759764

https://www.liferay.com/es/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/53005203

the issue is reported here:
https://issues.liferay.com/browse/IDE-1963

i quote:

> Thanks everyone for their involvement we are going to get this fixed in a bugfix only release in a few weeks for IDE v2.2.3
>
> The current recommendation is to use a GA3 SDK pointing at a GA4 environment in your build..properties file.

Comment: the bug is fixed now, just download the SDK as usual

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you download the Liferay Ide based on Eclipse Luna.

```
http://www.liferay.com/downloads/liferay-projects/liferay-ide
```

I create Liferay plugins with no problems.

Comment: downloaded Liferay Ide based on Eclipse Luna, but still gives me the same error. will try the permissions answer

Comment: Try update Liferay IDE 2.2.3 in Eclipse MarketPlace.