# Can't create my first portlet project using Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, liferay, portlet

I am new with liferay and I am using liferay-ce-portal-7.0-ga4 and eclipse

When I try to create my first portlet project it hangs like this:

[image]

and this is the console log:

[image: console log]

I read [Liferay - Error while creating first portlet plugin project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30151962/liferay-error-while-creating-first-portlet-plugin-project) but it didn't help me. I am using Windows 10.

Comment: Are you sure it hangs? Ivy is known to download quite a lot from the internet, especially on first start. Alternatively you might want to try creating a "Liferay Workspace" first, then a "Liferay Module Project" instead of utilizing Ant. The Plugins-SDK is being phased out and IMHO should only be used for migrating prior version's plugins to the current version.

Comment: I waited more than half an hour and nothing happened so I suppose it's hanging.
Note:I watched a video in which creating a portlet project took a few seconds!

Comment: understood. The key here is "first project" (where the ivy cache needs to be initialized) which is supposed to take longer than a few seconds. However, half an hour is also unexpected (unless you're on dialup). Try the workspace configuration nevertheless instead of ant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I connected to a more stable connection and waited a bit more. Project creation was successful! It seemed my connection was the problem.